# RatingBars and listeners in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I am new to Android and Java programming. I have a class which implements a custom cursor adapter. The problem is I need to be able to access some of the information in the cursor adapter within a listener. See below:

```
    public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{  
        public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, c);
        }

        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            TextView ratingBarName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar_name);
            ratingBarName.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDbAdapter.KEY_NAME)));

            RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
            ratingBar.setRating(cursor.getFloat(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDbAdapter.KEY_RATING)));


            RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener barListener = 
                new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromTouch) {
                    MyDbAdapter db = MyActivity.this.getDbHelper();

                    // NEED ACCESS TO CURSOR HERE SO I CAN DO:
                    // cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
                    // AND THEN USE THE ROW ID TO SAVE THE RATING IN THE DB
                    // HOW DO I DO THIS?
                }

            }               
            ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(barListener);
       }

       public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
           LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ratingrow, parent, false);
           bindView(view, context, cursor);
           return view;
       }
   }
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set as a tag for the `RatingBar` the `KEY_ROWID` before you enter in the listener and then in the listener retrieve the tag and use it on the cursor:

```
//...
ratingBar.setRating(cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDbAdapter.KEY_RATING)));
ratingBar.setTag(new Long(cursor.getLong(MyDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)));
RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener barListener = 
                new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromTouch) {
                    MyDbAdapter db = MyActivity.this.getDbHelper();                       
                    long theIdYouWant = (Long) ratingBar.getTag();                    
                    //use the id 
                }

            }    

//...
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your cursor final like this: **final** Cursor cursor

```
 public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just wondering - does having to do this indicate bad design or is changing to final commonly needed in this situation?

Comment: Your inner class (OnRatingBarChangeListener) cant get non final variables, so Yes it`s "commonly needed". Mark as resolved please.